# How to filter vmware_vm_facts

Tags: ansible, vmware

I'm trying to pull out the "uuid" from facts returned by ansible's vmware_vm_facts module. There is a solution to a similar question [posted on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ansible/comments/6wfu4d/filter_vmware_vm_facts/), but when I try that, it fails with 
'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'ip_address'

Here is my code:

```
  - name: Test vmware_vm_facts
    vmware_vm_facts:
      hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
      username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
      password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
      validate_certs: no
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: rc

  - name: Debug...
    debug:
      msg: "IP of {{ item.key }} is {{ item.value.ip_address }}and power is {{ item.value.power_state }}"
    with_dict: "{{ rc.virtual_machines }}"
```

Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Which ansible version are your running ? Can you please show a debug of your full `item` ?

Comment: I'm running Ansible 2.8Since posting this I have received an answer that works for me. I was

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your response @Zeitounator. I'm running Ansible 2.8
Since posting this I have received an answer that works for me. I realized that these facts are presented as a list of dicts as noted in the [doco](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/vmware_vm_facts_module.html), but I was still having trouble for some reason (confused myself badly.) The solution hinges on using with_items instead of with_dict and using an appropriate conditional like so:

```
  - name: Test vmware_vm_facts
    vmware_vm_facts:
      hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
      username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
      password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
      validate_certs: no
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: rc


  - debug:
      msg: "IP of {{ item.guest_name }} ({{ item.uuid }}) is {{ item.ip_address }} and power is {{ item.power_state }}"
    with_items: "{{ rc.virtual_machines }}"
    when: item.guest_name is search(inventory_hostname)
```